# when I try to generate a APK release a problem appears

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, release

When i trie to generate a APK release this problem came out.

BUILD OUTPUT

Explanation for issues of type "DuplicatePlatformClasses":
There are a number of libraries that duplicate not just functionality of
the Android platform but using the exact same class names as the ones
provided in Android -- for example the apache http classes. This can lead
to unexpected crashes.

To solve this, you need to either find a newer version of the library which
no longer has this problem, or to repackage the library (and all of its
dependencies) using something like the jarjar tool, or finally, rewriting
the code to use different APIs (for example, for http code, consider using
HttpUrlConnection or a library like okhttp).

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
 }

    android  {
        packagingOptions{
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

        }
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"


 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iza.letfly"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    }


 dependencies {


    implementation 'com.android.support:design:30.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
     implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.31.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.0'
     implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.2'
     implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
     implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.42.0'
     implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
     implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
     implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
     implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
     implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.38.1'
     implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:20.2.0'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.1'
     implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0'
     implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

  }

 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: What was the actual error you got?

Comment: I can't generete release apk because this error came out   :  Explanation for issues of type "DuplicatePlatformClasses": There are a number of libraries that duplicate not just functionality of the Android platform but using the exact same class names as the ones provided in Android -- for example the apache http classes. This can lead to unexpected crashes.

Comment: Error: commons-logging defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar.

Comment: Error: httpclient defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar.

Comment: Could you please share with us your solution